# Can you run Indigo on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to install Indigo on ubuntu 12.04?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189033/can-you-run-indigo-on-ubuntu-12.04?/) by [danbrooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/10921/danbrooks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to install Indigo on ubuntu 12.04?

Sorry for the spaces in the links, not enough karma.

I was able to install Indigo Desktop-full from source on Ubuntu 12.04. I basically followed the instructions posted at http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source, but needed to do a few extra steps.

First, install the prerequisites from the installation instructions. I already had ROS Hydro installed on my machine, and was able to install the dependencies from apt. Once the dependencies are installed the following should work.

Install lz4

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa: gezakovacs/lz4
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install liblz4-dev
```

Install OpenCV.
I initially tried using the opencv from the ubuntu repositories without success. Building and installing the latest version of OpenCV from source worked successfully. http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.zip/download

```
$ unzip opencv-2.4.9.zip 
$ cd opencv-2.4.9/
$ mkdir build
$ cd build/
$ cmake ..
$ make -j8
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Perform the first steps of the installation process

```
$ mkdir ~/ros_catkin_ws
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
$ rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --tar > indigo-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
$ wstool init -j8 src indigo-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall 
$ rosdep update
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

This last command will give you errors. This is because the dependencies really are not defined. However, most of these should be opencv related due to the fact rosdep does not know we installed it from source.

Install console_bridge

```
$ cd src/
$ git clone https://github.com/ros/console_bridge.git
$ cd console_bridge/
$ mkdir build
$ cd build/
$ cmake .. 
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ cd ../../..
```

Install urdfdom_headers

```
$ cd src/
$ git clone https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers.git
$ cd urdfdom_headers/
$ mkdir build
$ cd build/
$ cmake ..
$ sudo make install
$ cd ../../..
```

Install urdfdom

```
$ cd src/
$ git clone https://github.com/ros/urdfdom.git
$ cd urdfdom
$ mkdir build
$ cd build/
$ cmake ..
$ sudo make install
$ cd ../../..
```

Finally, start the build. Make sure you have not sourced any ROS setup.bash files.

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

You can resume building at the package you failed at using the following command.

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --from-pkg=<package name>
```

---

Originally posted by [danbrooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/10921/danbrooks/) with karma: 76 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-08-05**:
Using `console_bridge` from the source repository as-is will give you a very different version then what is used in Indigo on Trusty from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question has been answered before, but:

- officially: no, there is no support for Indigo on Ubuntu Precise. See [REP-3, Indigo Igloo](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014)
- unofficially: yes, but you have to build [from source](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source)
- alternatively: you could use [a chroot](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingIndigoInChroot) (although this is not technically Indigo on Precise, it does let you run it on your Precise installation without having to install Trusty), but please understand the limitations of this option

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danbrooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/10921/danbrooks/) on 2014-08-05**:
I actually have a set of instructions I'm trying to post for other people to use, but after I posted the question it would not let me answer my own question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-05**:
Seems I was a bit 'trigger happy' then. In any case: would a tutorial on the ROS wiki not be a more suitable place for this information?